# Is there something faster than a switch statement?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, switch-statement

When optimizing for performance, so far I'm led to believe that there is nothing faster than a switch statement. Is this the absolute truth?

Comment: Yes, it is the absolute truth.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Some NOPs are faster than others =P

Comment: @leemo, presumably, the OP already understands that if statements are on the *slower-than* side, not the *faster-than* side.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Indeed, that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing faster then an optimal algorithm (actually nothing at all is probably the fastest, then an optimal algorithm). Micro-optimizations involving switch vs if are rarely going to yield significant improvements on a modern system.
However, in limited circumstances (and on older computers) something like [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) were valuable (e.g. circa 1983 computers while doing computer animation on computers with extremely limited numbers of registers).

Answer (score 1):

At its heart, a switch statement is a series of jumps, which means O(n) performance. It is possible to use a hashtable as a jumptable, leading to O(1) performance. Unfortunately there are few hash algorithms other than identity that could be as fast or faster than the series of jumps and still provide the unique hash values required to identify which hash entry to examine.

Answer (score 0):

I made this test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int SwitchBase(int x)
{
    int TheReturn=22;
    switch (x)
    {
    case 1:
        TheReturn=1;
        break;
    case 2:
        TheReturn=2;
        break;
    case 3:
        TheReturn=3;
        break;
    case 4:
        TheReturn=4;
        break;
    case 5:
        TheReturn=5;
        break;
    case 6:
        TheReturn=6;
        break;
    case 7:
        TheReturn=7;
        break;
    case 8:
        TheReturn=8;
        break;
    case 9:
        TheReturn=9;
        break;
    case 10:
        TheReturn=10;
        break;
    default:
        TheReturn=0;
    }
    return TheReturn;
}

int BitwiseBase(int x)
{
    int TheReturn=22;
    TheReturn=
    ((((!(x^1))<< 31) >> 31) &1)
    |(((((x^1)&&(!(x^2)))<< 31) >> 31) &2)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(!(x^3)))<< 31) >> 31) &3)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(!(x^4)))<< 31) >> 31) &4)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(!(x^5)))<< 31) >> 31) &5)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(x^5)&&(!(x^6)))<< 31) >> 31) &6)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(x^5)&&(x^6)&&(!(x^7)))<< 31) >> 31) &7)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(x^5)&&(x^6)&&(x^7)&&(!(x^8)))<< 31) >> 31) &8)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(x^5)&&(x^6)&&(x^7)&&(x^8)&&(!(x^9)))<< 31) >> 31) &9)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(x^5)&&(x^6)&&(x^7)&&(x^8)&&(x^9)&&(!(x^10)))<< 31) >> 31) &10)
    |(((((x^1)&&(x^2)&&(x^3)&&(x^4)&&(x^5)&&(x^6)&&(x^7)&&(x^8)&&(x^9)&&(x^10))<< 31) >> 31) &0);
    return TheReturn;
}

int main()
{
    int randomnumber=23;
    int checknum=24;
    clock_t start, diff;
    srand(time(0));
    start = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        randomnumber = rand() % 11;
        checknum=SwitchBase(randomnumber);
        if (checknum!=randomnumber)
        {
            printf("s %i and %i",checknum,randomnumber);
        }
    }
    diff = clock() - start;

    int msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("SwitchBase Time taken %d milliseconds", msec);

    start = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        randomnumber = rand() % 11;
        checknum=BitwiseBase(randomnumber);
        if (checknum!=randomnumber)
        {
            printf("b %i and %i",checknum,randomnumber);
        }
    }
    diff = clock() - start;

    msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("BitwiseBase Time taken %d milliseconds", msec);

    return 0;
}
```

using codeblocks and a gcc compiler with -O2 checked. 
results:
SwitchBase Time taken  15 millisecondsBitwiseBase Time taken 31 milliseconds.
so Switch was still faster then bitwise in this case.